# WCF digital signature

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wcf, soap, digital-signature

I am developing WCF webservices for client to call. They use Java and they asked me to develop extra security with certificate behind it. I developed a service with custom certificate validation, and it works. When supplying proper certificate, it checks whether it is a correct certificate and allows/denies access to the server based on the validation result.

However, the following SOAP request is being generated when calling the service:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">MyCompanyName/IMyCompanyNameDSWCF/HelloWorld</a:Action>
        <h:OutOfBandData xmlns:h="http://www.examples.com">MyCompanyName</h:OutOfBandData>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</a:MessageID>
        <ActivityId CorrelationId="22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333</ActivityId>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_1">https://MyURL.com/MyCompanyName/MyCompanyNameDSWCF.svc?wsdl</a:To>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2015-05-25T16:16:49.530Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2015-05-25T16:21:49.530Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-44444444-4444-4444-4444-444444444444-44" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">value</o:BinarySecurityToken>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#_0">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>value</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#_1">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>value</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>value</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-44444444-4444-4444-4444-444444444444-44"/>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <HelloRequestMessage xmlns="MyCompanyName">
            <RequestToGreet xmlns="http://www.examples.com">MyCompanyName123</RequestToGreet>
        </HelloRequestMessage>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Unfortunately the client cannot generate same request. They provided a sample of the request they were able to provide, they call it "Digitally Signing" or what have you. This is a sample of their request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <dsig:Signature xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Id-1111111111111111-1111111111111111-2">
            <dsig:SignedInfo>
                <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                <dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                <dsig:Reference URI="#Id-1111111111111111-1111111111111111-1">
                    <dsig:Transforms>
                        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    </dsig:Transforms>
                    <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                    <dsig:DigestValue />
                </dsig:Reference>
            </dsig:SignedInfo>
            <dsig:SignatureValue />
            <dsig:KeyInfo xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Id-1111111111111111-1111111111111111-3">
                <dsig:X509Data>
                    <dsig:X509Certificate>
                        value
                    </dsig:X509Certificate>
                </dsig:X509Data>
            </dsig:KeyInfo>
        </dsig:Signature>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-1111111111111111-1111111111111111-1">
        <HelloRequestMessage xmlns="MyCompanyName">
            <RequestToGreet xmlns="http://www.examples.com">MyCompanyName123</RequestToGreet>
        </HelloRequestMessage>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I've researched for days with no luck: 
- I don't know how to sign a request on the client side (my test app calling my WCF WS);
- I don't know how to configure WCF to accept and validate digitally signed requests;

PS: my WCF is only about 3 weeks old, so please try to explain as if I know nothing about it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to intercept the message to fix it - the client should be able to send the request to the service based on the information provided in the WSDL.   The only difference I see (at a glance) between the request you generated and the request the client generated is that your request's signature is wrapped in a `<Security>` element.  What happens when the client sends their request?  Do they get an error?

Comment: Client cannot generate a request wrapped in Security tag. They sent me a sample of their request with Signature tag asking me to implement WS this way. So I am trying to configure WCF to accept their request and validate the signature per their specs.